# How to make Linux discover new LUNs from Pure Storage FlashArray//X70 R3?

Tags: linux, storage, storage-area-network, fibre-channel

When a new LUNs are presented to Fibre Channel SAN from a Pure Storage FlashArray//X70 R3, Linux (SLES) does not find those (as opposed to other FC storage systems like the HP EVA or 3PAR StorServ).
Even after a `rescan-scsi-bus.sh` the new LUNs are not detected by the Linux kernel.

The only two methods that are known to work are:

1. Reboot the machine after the LUN mappings have changed.
2. Use option `-i` for `rescan-scsi-bus.sh`, re-initializing the loop via LIP primitive.

The second method causes I/O errors for existing LUNs on the loop when they are being accessed while LIP is executing.

Naturally for an enterprise server or even HA cluster neither frequent reboots nor collateral I/O errors are acceptable as a solution.
It doesn't help that I wouldn't have bought that storage system.
It's there now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried;

echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan

Bit old-school but it works, not sure if it's any better than option 2 however.

Comment: I cannot try it at the moment, but my guess was that `rescan-scsi-bus.sh` does the same thing, just a bit more selective. If so, that would not be the answer most likely.